# how to remove the above elements from list from matrix by python

Tags: python

```
matrixA = 
[['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
['PPP', 'QQQ', 'RRR', 'SSS'],
['DDD','EEE','FFF'],
['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
```

how to remove the above elements from listA from matrixA

```
listA = ['DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF']
```

Desired output:

```
output_matrix = 
[['DDD','EEE','FFF'],
['GGG', 'HHH', 'III']]
```

sorry for my bad language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `index` of `listA` within `matrixA` and then slice with it:

```
idx = matrixA.index(listA)
out = matrixA[idx:]
```

to get

```
>>> out

[["DDD", "EEE", "FFF"], ["GGG", "HHH", "III"]]
```

---

in case `listA` doesn't exist, it gives an error so we `try`:

```
try:
    idx = matrixA.index(listA)
except ValueError:
    # if it doesn't exist..
    out = matrixA          # we can take the whole `matrixA`, for example
else:
    # it does exist
    out = matrixA[idx:]
```

Comment: Better to add index in try ecept it will give value error if the `listA` isnt existing in `matrixA`